# ManyToMany filter not working Django

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-models

I have the following models

```
class A(models.Model)
    a_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    created_by_id = models.ManyToManyField(User,db_column="user_id", related_name="created_by_id")
    last_updated_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, db_column="user_id", related_name="last_updated_by",)
    resolved_by_id = models.ManyToManyField(User, db_column="user_id", related_name='resolved_by_id')

class B(models.Model):
    ....

class C(models.Model):
    ....

class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=30)

    field_1 = models.ForeignKey(B)
    field_2 = models.ForeignKey(C)
```

when I apply serialization on the `class A` I get the following error in SQL table not found, I am using OracleDB

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

('SELECT "USER"."USER_ID", "USER"."USER_NAME" FROM "USER" INNER '
 'JOIN "A_CREATED_BY_ID" ON ("USER"."USER_ID" = '
 '"A_CREATED_BY_ID"."USERMST") WHERE '
 '"A_CREATED_BY_ID"."A_ID" = %s')
```

I have looked into the Django docs for ManytoMany still unable to figure out what the problem was.

**Update**: This is on a Legacy Database and we are not using migrations

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a legacy database, Django didn't create the tables and thus doesn't know about the intermediate tables used by the ManyToManyFields. You have to let Django know which tables it should use for the joins.
For example:

```
created_by_id = models.ManyToManyField(
    User,
    through="ModelName" # the model name
    db_table="table_name" # the table name in the DB for the join
    db_column="user_id", # this one you could drop
    related_name="created_by_id"
)
```

You should rather specify then the `db_column` in the model that connects class A and class User.

Also you could add `class Meta` to your models:

```
class Meta:
    managed = False
```

That makes it obvious for everybody who's reading the code, that the database isn't managed by Django.

EDIT:
Here is a [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) to the official documentation about the option `through`.